# Get a handle of Menu option

Tags: c#, windows, spy++

I am trying to control another application with my C# code on Win 7.

I need to programmatically click an option in the menu [image: Screenshot from the application]

I am successfully sending keys to that application, or pressing a "stand-alone" button in that application with:
`SendMessage`
Spy++ gives me a button's handle, so that SendMessage can hit that button, however I am not able to figure out how to get a handle to the menu item and hit that option (I tried iterating though children of he parent handle, but no luck).

Comment: Have you tried using Inspect.exe?  UIA is able to automate many more applications than Spy++ will guide you to.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/inspect-objects

Comment: You probably want to take the UI Automation path. That menu will have a handle when it's created. But, with UIA, you don't need a handle.

Comment: Menu items don't have handles, Win32 menu functions identify them either by position or by ID. That said, have you tried sending WM_COMMAND instead?